# Embed Images Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am having an issue with images in embeds.

I am choosing a random string from a list (which is a link to a cat image) and then the embed is supposed to post that image, however, it isn't and it just looks like this:

[image]

If I put the links into my browser they work fine.
I tried using import `random` and `random.choice` but that did not work either.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from datetime import datetime
import random

class catc:
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
    @commands.command(pass_context=True)
    async def cat(self, ctx):
        f=open("cat.txt","r")
        v=f.read()
        f.close()
        fi = v.split(',')
        pe=random.randint(0,41)
        re=fi[pe]
        print(re)
        embed = discord.Embed(title="title", color=0x309bf3)
        embed.set_image(url="https://i.imgur.com/xJifyGMb.jpg")
        embed.set_footer(text="Nami Bot")
        await self.bot.say(embed=embed)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(catc(bot))
```

Answer (score 0):

So in order to get your code working, you have to change the URL of your picture to anything else
For example, I've re-uploaded the same picture to imgur and pasted the link and now it works

`embed.set_image(url="https://i.imgur.com/SJgskbM.jpg")`

This might have something to do with imgur direct links but I don't know for sure

[image]

Full working code:

> The cog (cat_pics.py)

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random

class catc:
  def __init__(self, bot):
    self.bot = bot
  @commands.command(pass_context=True)
  async def cat(self, ctx):
    with open('something.txt') as f:
      mylist = list(f)
    a = random.choice(mylist)
    print(a)
    embed = discord.Embed(title="title", color=0x309bf3)
    embed.set_image(url="https://i.imgur.com/SJgskbM.jpg")
    embed.set_footer(text="Nami Bot")
    await self.bot.say(embed=embed)

def setup(bot):
  bot.add_cog(catc(bot))
```

> main.py

````
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

startup_extensions = ["cat_pics"]
client = Bot(command_prefix='!')

@client.command()
async def load(extension_name : str):
  """Loads an extension."""
  try:
    client.load_extension(extension_name)
  except (AttributeError, ImportError) as e:
    await client.say("```py\n{}: {}\n```".format(type(e).__name__, str(e)))
    return
  await client.say("{} loaded.".format(extension_name))


if __name__ == "__main__":
  for extension in startup_extensions:
    try:
      client.load_extension(extension)
    except Exception as e:
      exc = '{}: {}'.format(type(e).__name__, e)
      print('Failed to load extension {}\n{}'.format(extension, exc))

  client.run('TOKEN')
````

Comment: Yep. I know it sounds stupid but I tried it again and it still doesn't work with any imgur links.

Comment: The new url seems to be working for me, I'll post the entire code, see if there's any differences that might be interfering with it working